# OpenGL-2.9.2.0 fails to compile with ghc 7.10.1

Tags: haskell, ghc, hsqml

Any idea what causing this ? And how can one fix it ?

```
joco@vm001:~$ cabal install hsqml-demo-samples
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring OpenGL-2.9.2.0...
Building OpenGL-2.9.2.0...
Failed to install OpenGL-2.9.2.0
Build log ( /home/joco/.cabal/logs/OpenGL-2.9.2.0.log ):
Configuring OpenGL-2.9.2.0...
Building OpenGL-2.9.2.0...
Preprocessing library OpenGL-2.9.2.0...
[  1 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.VertexAttributes ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/VertexAttributes.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/VertexAttributes.o )

Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/VertexAttributes.hs:25:1: Warning:
    The import of ‘Control.Applicative’ is redundant
      except perhaps to import instances from ‘Control.Applicative’
    To import instances alone, use: import Control.Applicative()
[  2 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.Texturing.Filter ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/Texturing/Filter.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/Texturing/Filter.o )
[  3 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.PointParameter ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/PointParameter.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/PointParameter.o )
[  4 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.PixelFormat ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/PixelFormat.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/PixelFormat.o )
[  5 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.ComparisonFunction ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/ComparisonFunction.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/ComparisonFunction.o )
[  6 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.BlendingFactor ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/BlendingFactor.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/BlendingFactor.o )
[  7 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.Texturing.PixelInternalFormat ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/Texturing/PixelInternalFormat.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/Texturing/PixelInternalFormat.o )
[  8 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.FramebufferObjects.FramebufferTarget ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/FramebufferObjects/FramebufferTarget.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/FramebufferObjects/FramebufferTarget.o )
[  9 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.BufferMode ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/BufferMode.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/BufferMode.o )
[ 10 of 117] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL.GL.IOState ( Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.hs, dist/build/Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.o )

Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.hs:32:10:
    No instance for (Applicative (IOState s))
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monad (IOState s)’

Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.hs:45:4:
    Could not deduce (Applicative (IOState a))
      arising from a do statement
    from the context (Storable a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 peekIOState :: Storable a => IOState a a
      at Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.hs:43:16-40
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: ptr <- getIOState
    In the expression:
      do { ptr <- getIOState;
           x <- liftIOState $ peek ptr;
           putIOState (ptr `plusPtr` sizeOf x);
           return x }
    In an equation for ‘peekIOState’:
        peekIOState
          = do { ptr <- getIOState;
                 x <- liftIOState $ peek ptr;
                 putIOState (ptr `plusPtr` sizeOf x);
                 .... }

Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.hs:57:12:
    Could not deduce (Applicative (IOState b))
      arising from a use of ‘replicateM’
    from the context (Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 nTimes :: Integral a => a -> IOState b c -> IOState b [c]
      at Graphics/Rendering/OpenGL/GL/IOState.hs:56:11-57
    In the expression: replicateM (fromIntegral n)
    In an equation for ‘nTimes’: nTimes n = replicateM (fromIntegral n)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
OpenGL-2.9.2.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
hsqml-demo-samples-0.3.3.0 depends on OpenGL-2.9.2.0 which failed to install.
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is for the old version of OpenGL only. Newer versions should build ok. https://travis-ci.org/haskell-opengl/OpenGL